# CF7 dropdown menu limit quantity

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, conditional-statements, contact-form-7

I am trying to build a contact form that allows the user to select a school date and I want to limit the number of submissions to not overbook the class. I typically offer one class a week and there are a maximum of 12 seats in each class. I have been searching everywhere and I cannot find a way to restrict a selection in a dropdown menu to only allow it to be submitted 12 times. So for instance if in the dropdown my next class is April 9th once that form has been submitted with the selection of April 9th 12 times I need to have April 9th grayed out and no longer selectable. I have tried multiple booking calendar plugins and they are all too complex for this simple task or not complex enough and I really like the way my existing contact form 7 already works because it is one of the only forms that allow for a signature field. I just need to be able to limit the selection for one specific question in the contact form. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am currently using the smart grid layout and this is the code I inserted into the functions.php file

```
    add_filter( 
'cf7sg_dynamic_dropdown_custom_options','dayClass_dynamic_options',10,3);

function dayClass_dynamic_options($options, $name, $cf7_key){
  if('training-school-application_copy'!==$cf7_key || 'dayClass' !== $name){
    return $options;
  } 

  $data = array (
    'April 16th - 17th' => "val1",
    'May 21st - 22nd' => "val2",
    'June 18th - 19th' => "val3",
    'July 16th - 17th' => "val4",
  );

    $options='<option value="">Select a Date</option>'.PHP_EOL;
    foreach($data as $label=>$value){
      $options .= '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$label.'</option>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
  return $options;
}

add_filter( 
'cf7sg_dynamic_dropdown_custom_options','recert_dynamic_options',10,3);

function recert_dynamic_options($options, $name, $cf7_key){
  if('training-school-application_copy'!==$cf7_key || 'recert' !== $name){
    return $options;
  } 

  $data2 = array (
    'April 6th' => "val1",
    'May 4th' => "val2",
    'June 1st' => "val3",
    'July 6th' => "val4",
  );

    $options='<option value="">Select a Date</option>'.PHP_EOL;
    foreach($data2 as $label=>$value){
      $options .= '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$label.'</option>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
  return $options;
}

add_filter( 
'cf7sg_dynamic_dropdown_custom_options','combo_dynamic_options',10,3);

function combo_dynamic_options($options, $name, $cf7_key){
  if('training-school-application_copy'!==$cf7_key || 'combo' !== $name){
    return $options;
  } 

  $data3 = array (
    'April 14th - 17th' => "val1",
    'May 19th - 22nd' => "val2",
    'June 16th - 19th' => "val3",
    'July 14th - 17th' => "val4",
  );

    $options='<option value="">Select a Date</option>'.PHP_EOL;
    foreach($data3 as $label=>$value){
      $options .= '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$label.'</option>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
  return $options;
}
```

I then inserted this code into the contact form which I am using conditional fields to show the corresponding group based on a selection from a previous question in the form

```
 <div class="halfWidth">
 [group dayClass][dynamic_select custom-list1 class:select2 "source:filter"] 
 [/group]
 [group recert][dynamic_select custom-list2 class:select2 "source:filter"] 
 [/group]
 [group combo][dynamic_select custom-list3 class:select2 "source:filter"] 
 [/group]
 </div>
```

I do not know how to limit the selections to a maximum of 12 selections per option? Can someone please show me how to limit and hide the date values once the have been submitted 12 times?

Comment: One way to achieve this is to use the dynamic dropdown field available in the [Smart Grid layout extension for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) plugin.  The dynamic dropdown can be populated using a filter function in your functions.php file where you can consult your DB and show classes with available sears.  See this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9he4Tca5o8&t=1198s).

Comment: I followed the tutorial exactly as he did and yet nothing seems to be working. I added the exact code he does in the tutorial and I am still getting no results found in the dropdown box.

Comment: try using [v4.9](https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/cf7-grid-layout.4.9.zip), the current version has an [issue](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/dynamic-dropdown-does-not-work-in-v4-10-0/) with filtered dynamic lists.

Comment: Thank you, downgrading the plugin fixed my issue and now the fields appear dynamically how they should. Now from this point how do I limit the selections to a maximum of 12?

Comment: how do you track your class available slots?

Comment: Currently I do not. It has all been manual when I print out the form but I often forget to log in and close out the class dates so I keep overbooking classes which is why I am trying to automate it but I do not know php well enough to write my own code so I have been researching and trying to teach myself. Normally I research and find something similar and then copy and edit the code until it works but I cannot find anything like what I am trying to do.