# Limit submissions based on availability for specific field in Contact Form 7, which is connected to Google Sheets

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets, conditional-formatting, contact-form-7

I am trying to limit the number of times an option can be selected in CF7. I am using the Conditional Fields for Contact Form and also CF7 Google Sheet Connector Pro.
Specifically, I need a dropdown where the number of submissions already made determines what is shown.
**For example:**
Which activity do you choose?

> -Answer A
> -Answer B
> -Answer C
> If "Answer A" has already been chosen by previous users 12 times, I would like it grayed out or otherwise unable to be selected.
> Submissions are connected to a Google Sheet.

I struggle with php so answers [like the one in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67007426/cf7-dropdown-menu-limit-quantity/78003191?noredirect=1#comment137515606_78003191) are a challenge, because I'm unclear about what I should change to apply it to my own situation. I appreciate any insight.

I also watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9he4Tca5o8&t=1198s) but it doesn't directly answer my question. I am willing to get the Smart Grid plugin but after watching many videos, am not sure how to handle the google sheets integration and have it feed back and interpret a total number of submissions for that field.

Any advice is appreciated.